# How do I install java3d in java8

Tags: java

I tried to install java3d and have done something incorrectly since java is crashing. Here is what I did:

Went to "Download Java 3D 1.5.1 Software" which went to my downloads directory.
Changed to properties to run as executable on java3d-1_5_1-linux-amd64.bin and ran it. That made a lib folder in downloads containing amd64 with 1 file and an ext folder with 3 files.

From there I went to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib which had the same amd64 and ext folders which did not contain the files in the java3d. I copied and pasted the files.

I am doing something wrong because when I attempt to run java, using 3d, it crashes out of java. So my question is: where should I have placed the files so that it would work? If this is the wrong way to do things, what is the correct way?