# installation of openjdk-8 vs oracle jdk8

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk, oracle, netbeans

I am using Netbeans which I prefer Oracle jdk8. Just now Ubuntu said I had an incomplete upgrade to 16.04. No problem, I let it do its thing.

To my surprise it removed Oracle JDK and put openjdk in its place. Apparently Ubuntu must have openjdk-8?? If it removed my Oracle jdk, that implies that I can't have both?

I don't care if Ubuntu wants openjdk for its own purposes, but how do get back my Oracle JDK for Netbeans? Can I install it alongside the openjdk? Then I can use the Oracle for Netbeans and let Ubuntu do whatever it wants with the openjdk?

Comment: Here you go: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Comment: It worked, thanks. Since you know about Java, I'll ask another question. There is java 3d: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-jsp-138252.html I am trying to use it java8 but it doesn't work. I asked here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/770224/how-do-i-install-java3d-in-java8 but nobody seems to know the answer.

Comment: I would like to know why you need Oracle JDK. AFAIK there are no significant differences at least for small and not very sofisticated projects, could you give me some information? Thanks.

Comment: A while back I had troubles upgrading Netbeans. Someone from Oracle was gracious enough to help me, and he suggested life would be easier if I used the Oracle JDK. Whatever the reason, Netbeans loaded for me. A while back, in fact I did use openjdk, so basically I agree with you. In any case Netbeans is central to my development effort, so I took the path of least resistance. Not a great reason, but...

Comment: In fact in my question to Ask Ubuntu on the java3d, I used Oracle Java8 and it failed to work with the java3d. I was thinking about trying openjdk that perhaps that might work with Java3d. I suspect the real problem is that java3d works with java6 and not with java8. However, I don't really know, which is the reason I asked the question.